# HttpContextBase.User.Identity.Name is empty with WindowsAuthentification true, anonymous false, and Authorize tag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

For some reason I can't authenticate when debugging (HttpContextBase.User.Identity.Name returns string.Empty which results in a 401 error), even after setting:

```
<system.web><authentication mode="Windows" /></system.web>
```

... and adding [Authorize] tags on anything that might require it.

What could I be missing?

Additional information: this is within the definition of an implementation/inheritance of AuthorizeAttribute.

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution and since I've never seen this answer for any other similar question:

The issue stems from using IIS Express, which seems to ignore the  tab in favor of the project's properties.

So correct it by modifying the web site's properties (select the project and hit F4 to see the properties) to change Windows authentication to active and deactivate anonymous authentication.